Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

What does 飘然而至 mean?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


How to say "thank you for ..."?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


Characters used to specify low/standard/medium/high quality/definition in video sharing websites

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)


連連 Trying to understand the double word (叠词 or 叠字) usage

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)


How can I find the exact written versions of commonly spoken Cantonese words?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


How to express: Get

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)


(麻薯), what kind, if not then what is it?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


I did (Something) as much as I would in (X amount of time)

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)


道 vs 途 in religious texts

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to ask girl for number?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)


I drop in just occasionally and am pretty much a newbie on this site.  My impression is that people here are pretty helpful, and give good respect.  Answers are often excellent.   
Specifically as to patterns of questions, I think this site is pretty accepting, and that is good.  Some do get closed.  They should.  But I don't see any pattern that needs more criticism.   
